# cl-lib isn't loaded the first time an autoloaded function is used from it

Tags: autoload, require, cl-lib

I'm trying to use `cl-lib` early in my `init.el`.  The function I'm using (`cl-some`) is autoloaded, so I expect that don't need an explicit `require`, yet I get a void-function error if I don't explicitly `require`.  Sounds like other people have this problem as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30848971/245173

```
;; OK
(require 'cl-lib)
(cl-some #'identity '(nil))
```

---

```
;; void-function the first time, OK subsequently
(cl-some #'identity '(nil))
```

Why is `require` necessary if the function is marked for autoloading?  Why does it generate an error and also load the library?

Update: if I `(load-library "cl-loaddefs.el")`, which is where the autoload for `cl-some` is, it works correctly the first time.  So it seems like `cl-loaddefs` isn't being loaded.  Why not?

Answer (score 3):

It's an internal autoload of the cl-lib package, not a global autoload. cl- has no global autoloads.
To use cl- functions, require cl-lib.
To use cl- macros, eval-when-compile require cl-lib.

Comment: Fair enough.  It still seems super weird.  For example, `cl-evenp` is in `cl-lib`, is not marked for autoloading (at least with a `;;;###autoload` comment), and depends only on builtins.  It behaves the same way as `cl-some`: fails with void-function on the first invocation, gets autoloaded anyway, and works on subsequent invocations.

Answer (score 1):

As ocoh2 points out, `cl-lib` is not autoloaded, the only way to get it is to `require` it or have it indirectly autoloaded (some autoloaded package `require`s it).

It must be the Debugger that loads `cl-lib`.  With `emacs -Q --eval '(cl-evenp 2)'`, there is an error but no debugger and `cl-lib` is not loaded.  `cl-lib` only gets loaded after the Debugger pops up once Emacs is running interactively.  I still don't understand why `cl-lib` is not autoloaded (though I'm not very surprised given the avoidance of `cl-lib` in a lot of Emacs), but at least everything is consistent.